# does render() method in express.js ends the response automatically?

Tags: express

I am fairly new to the express.js framework and from what I understood of node.js a response should always be closed using end() method otherwise it would be left pending. So is this done automatically by a method such as render() in express.js?

Answer (score 0):

You should **not** always use `res.end` to end the response process. From [Express 4.x API Reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end):

> #### res.end([data] [, encoding])
>
> Ends the response process. This method actually comes from Node core, specifically the `response.end()` method of `http.ServerResponse`.
>
> Use to quickly end the response without any data. If you need to respond with data, instead use methods such as `res.send()` and `res.json()`.

`res.render` will render the given view and send the rendered HTML string to the client, ending the response.